# Sorting Sets using std::sort

Tags: c++, stl, set

I would like to know if we can sort a pre created set. When I first create the set s_p2, I sort using a different element point.getLength(). but after user input i would like to sort the items according to the x value point.getX(). How i do this ?

It seems like set container does not have a sort function. And i am advised to use vector.
But sets are able to store unique elements only.

Q1: How can i sort a set depending on the criteria

Q2: If set is unable to do this than which STL container is the best choice and how can i sort the elements in the container.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You cannot resort a `set`, how it sorts is part of the type of the particular `set`.  A given `set` has a fixed set order that cannot be changed.

You could create a new `set` with the same data relatively easily.  Just create a new `set` that sorts based on the new criteria.

If you want to use the two `set`s in the same code, you'll have to abstract the access to the underlying `set`.

Now, if you are doing rare reads and modifications, using a `vector` that you sort manually is often a better idea.  You can remove duplicates by using the `std::unique`-`erase` idiom.

Comment: Vector is ok with me. but i am not sure how to implement the std::unique-erase . Can u advise ?

Comment: @user1571494: Given a sorted vector, `v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end()), v.end());` will remove duplicates.

Comment: Note that the above code @Mike wrote will use `operator==` to compare them.  You may need to pass in a predicate so that you only nuke things that are sort-equivalent `(!(a<b) && !(b<a))`

Comment: Also note that don't miss that last `, v.end()` -- it will compile, but won't do anything sensible, but may pass a few manual tests.

Answer (score 10):

`std::set` stores its members in a sorted fashion. If you walk through the set from `.begin()` to `.end()`, you will have a sorted list of items.

If you don't like the default sort criteria, you may supply a 2nd template parameter to `std::set<>`

Comment: Yup.. I understand. but can i re-sort it

Comment: @user1571494 - No, you cannot re-sort it. You *can* copy the items out of that `std::set<>` and into a different container -- perhaps a `std::set` with a different comparison template parameter.

Comment: I believe sets accept a comparator, or an object (either to a pointer to a function or a class with a function call operator) that is capable of taking 2 objects in the set and determining an absolute order between them.  If you look at the example on the bottom of this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/set/, there is an example of a set with a custom comparator.

Answer (score 4):

You can have two sets and keep them in sync or copy one to the other.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

struct AB
{
   AB(int a,int b) : _a(a),_b(b) {}

   int _a;
   int _b;
};

struct byA
{
    bool operator () (const AB& lhs, const AB& rhs)
    {
          return lhs._a <= rhs._a;
    }
}; 

struct byB
{
    bool operator () (const AB& lhs, const AB& rhs)
    {
       return lhs._b <= rhs._b;
    }
}; 

typedef set<AB,byA> ByA;
typedef set<AB,byB> ByB;
typedef ByA::const_iterator ByAIt;
typedef ByB::const_iterator ByBIt;

void getByB(const ByA &sA,ByB &sB)
{
   for(ByAIt iter=sA.begin(); iter!=sA.end();++iter) {
      const AB &ab=*iter;
      sB.insert(ab);
   }
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
   ByA sA;
   sA.insert(AB(3,6));
   sA.insert(AB(1,8));
   sA.insert(AB(2,7));

   ByB sB;
   getByB(sA,sB);

   cout << "ByA:" << endl;
   for(ByAIt iter=sA.begin(); iter!=sA.end();++iter) {
      const AB &ab=*iter;
      cout << ab._a << "," << ab._b << " ";
   }
   cout << endl << endl;

   cout << "ByB:" << endl;
   for(ByBIt iter=sB.begin(); iter!=sB.end();++iter) {
      const AB &ab=*iter;
      cout << ab._a << "," << ab._b << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

program returns:
ByA 
1,8 2,7 3,6

ByB:
3,6 2,7 1,8