# Custom Ordering in Set String Elements

Tags: c++, sorting, set

`std::set<std::string> &uniq_email_list;`

I have a set of many email elements, for examples:

`('foo@bar.com', 'foo2@bar.com', 'foo@bazz.com', 'foo2@bazz.com','zfoo@bar.com')`

then I write these elements to a file

```
for(iter = uniq_email_list.begin() ; iter!=uniq_email_list.end(); ++iter){  
            output_file<< *iter << std::endl;
        }
```

Before I write these elements to the file, I want to sort by '@' next domain name
and I want it to look like this in the file

```
foo@bar.com
foo2@bar.com
zfoo@bar.com
foo@bazz.com
foo2@bazz.com
```

And I know

You cannot resort a set, how it sorts is part of the type of the particular set. A given set has a fixed set order that cannot be changed.

You could create a new set with the same data relatively easily. Just create a new set that sorts based on the new criteria

I read that post [Sorting Sets using std::sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385348/sorting-sets-using-stdsort)
But I couldn't find the answer to my problem.

As a result of my research I found something like

```
std::set<string>::iterator &it;
it=myset.find('@');
```

Can I sort by the returned address with this structure? Or if there are other solutions suitable for this problem, thank you in advance, I am ready to get advice on issues related to C ++ solutions.

Comment: Please do not use "C/C++". C and C++ are very different languages. What you show is clearly no C.

Comment: What does "this structure" mean? No, a `std::set` cannot be sorted, no matter what other structures exist in the code.

Comment: You can set custom comparator to `std::set`. [std::set<Key,Compare,Allocator>::set - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set)

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to use the domain and name parts individually, I suggest that you split them up and put them in an `email` class for which you provide an `operator<` that fulfills the [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) requirement needed to create a `std::set<email>`:

```cpp
#include <tuple>  // std::tie

struct email {
    std::string name;
    std::string domain;

    // The compare operator used by default by a std::set<email>:
    bool operator<(const email& rhs) const {

        // using std::tie makes creating an operator< that does
        // strict weak ordering relatively easy:

        return std::tie(domain, name) < std::tie(rhs.domain, rhs.name);
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const email& e) {
    os << e.name;
    if(not e.domain.empty()) os << '@' << e.domain;
    return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, email& e) {
    if(std::string tmp; is >> tmp) {

        auto at_pos = tmp.find('@');        
        e.name = tmp.substr(0, at_pos);

        if(at_pos != std::string::npos) {    
            e.domain = tmp.substr(at_pos + 1);
        } else {
            e.domain.clear();
        }
    }
    return is;
}
```

You can now put them in a `std::set<email>` or in a `std::vector<email>` (and `std::sort` that vector) and stream them out in the order specified by the member `operator<`. Domain first, name last and also read from streams:

```cpp
email tmp;
while(instream >> tmp) {
    std::cout << "read address: " << tmp << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/bvh8nx)

Answer (score 2):

```cpp
class EmailCompare
{
public:
    bool operator()(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) const {
        // your code here
        return ... ;
    }
};

using EmailSet = std::set<std::string, EmailCompare>;
```

Comment: fwiw, I answered along the same line, but only now realized that using a custom comparator that only compares the part after `@`, one cannot have `foo2@bar.com` and
`zfoo@bar.com` in the set at the same time. Maybe there is an obvious solution that I don't see...

Comment: `// your code here` should compare not only host but user too.

Comment: yeah makes sense, instead of comparing `foo2@bar.com` vs `zfoo@bar.com` compare `@bar.comfoo2` vs `@bar.comzfoo`.