# How can I make map of set in c++ where elements in sets are sorted in decreasing order?

Tags: c++, dictionary, set, comparator

```
auto cmpli = [](const int &a, const int &b)
    {
        return a > b;
    };

    map<int, set<int, decltype(cmpli)>(cmpli)>ms;
    ms[1].insert(13);
    ms[1].insert(10);
    ms[1].insert(23);
    ms[2].insert(33);
    ms[2].insert(3);

    for (auto s : ms)
    {
        for (auto e : s.second)
            cout << e << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
```

// expected output: 23,13,10,33,3

> Blockquote How can I make map of set in c++ where elements in sets are sorted in decreasing order?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting Sets using std::sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385348/sorting-sets-using-stdsort)

Comment: Drop `cmpli`, make it `set<int, std::greater<int>>`. The line `map<int, set<int, decltype(cmpli)>(cmpli)>ms;` is nonsense, and doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the syntax.

You have probably seen `set<int, decltype(cmpli)>> ms(cmpli);`, where `set<int, decltype(cmpli)>>` is the type, `ms` is the variable name, and `(cmpli)` is the initializer.

But `map<int, set<int, decltype(cmpli)>(cmpli)> ms;` doesn't make sense, you can't specify default initializers for elements (or what was it?) like this.

There are several options:

- You can switch to C++20 or newer and just drop `(cmpli)`. Capture-less lambdas became default-constructible, so everything should just work.
- Make `cmpli` a regular function, and replace `decltype(cmpli)` with `std::integral_constant<decltype(&cmpli), cmpli>`. Also drop `(cmpli)`.
- Replace a custom comparator with `std::greater`: `map<int, set<int, greater<>>> ms;`. You could also use `greater<int>`, but `greater<>` has some useful properties, though they don't matter in this case (look up transparent comparators).

Comment: Any good resources for these kind of advanced topics? Like I have studied c++ but not taught these topics.

Comment: @Omprakashkumar I've heard good things about [those books](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2752075), but I haven't read those. Ultimately, you have to learn on your own; don't expect teachers or courses to give you much, there are very few good ones.

Comment: Also, my map is  map<string,set<pair<int,string>>>m;
Can I use greater<> here? if not what are other solution?

Comment: @Omprakashkumar Yes, you can. If you don't specify any comparator, the default one is `less<T>` which calls `<`. And `greater` calls `>`. If a type supports `<`, it most probably supports `>`.